# Xbox One S startup error: While trying to switch from retail to Dev mode, it crashed with error series E200

Tags: uwp, xbox-one

Also, the Dev mode activation app is stuck @ step 4 (I think it's a [known issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/bugdev-mode-activation-wants-to-update-but-there/5bc72d9e-9d23-4330-8813-36da58be541a))

And Devkit App stops with `0x8027025a error`.

Is anyone else facing a similar problem?‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏

Comment: Could you please tell me if Edward_McInnish’s solution in your [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/bugdev-mode-activation-wants-to-update-but-there/5bc72d9e-9d23-4330-8813-36da58be541a) has resolved your question?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Edward_McInnish’s answer definitely helps me discover the hidden developer option. But the restart after enabling dev mode crashes with a startup error!

Comment: You could try to refer to the [document](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/errors/error-code-8027025a) to see if it can resolve your startup error.